# How to find both endpoints of a 2D line segment given a list of points on said line segment?

Tags: geometry

Imagine you have a list of points, say:

6,4 |
5,3.5 |
4,3 |
3,2.5 |
2,2 |
1,1.5 |
0,1

How would you mathematically find the two endpoints of the line segment? I need a solution that covers all scenarios, like if the *y* is always the same, or if some points are in quadrant 2 or 3 (Below 0).

The answer to this scenario would be 6,4 | 0,1

I haven't tried anything, because, well, I know jack about math. Thanks!

Comment: Endpoints of a _line segment_

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing, like I said. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Not the most efficient, but for simplicity you can’t beat “choose the two points from the set that are the farthest apart.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose any two points on the line (I am assuming all points actually fall on a single line).  Let these two points be $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2)$.  Find the direction vector

$ d = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1) $

Then all the points can be written as

$(x_i, y_i) = (x_1 , y_1) + t_i d $

Here, $t_1 = 0 $ , $t_2 = 1 $.  Find the $t_i$'s for all the other points, then find the minimum and maximum $t_i$ and the corresponding index, these points are the endpoints of the line segment.

Alternatively, you can sort the list of points according to the  $x$ coordinate.  The top and bottom of the list are the end points.  If all points have the same $x$ coordinate, then sort them according to the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: The second method worked for me, thanks!